# Python operation order

Tags: python, operation

So my question is I have this number that is `4**2**3` when put into python it says its equal to `65536`. For some reason when I try to calculate it myself from left to right I get the answer `4096`. I was wondering if someone could help me out with this and explain what to do to get the correct answer? Thank you very much!

Comment: `4**2**3 = 4**(2**3) = 4**8 = 65536` You're probably doing: `(4**2)**3 = 4096`

Comment: Where and how are you "putting into python?"  We need more of context to be helpful here.

Comment: Just into the interactive python shell.

Comment: You type >>>423 and get back 65536? I don't think so.

Comment: @gregory: He doesn't have any code ticks on the thing. The bold two means he's actually typing: `4**2**3`

Comment: @Dair, Ah, silly me. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome thank you @Dair has answered my question just a silly calculating error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that, mathematically, you're asking 4 ^ 2 ^ 3 and are getting tripped up due to bolding...

Python is computing it as 4 ^ (2 ^ 3). In order to get it as 4096, do (4 ^ 2) ^ 3

```
(4 ** 2) ** 3
```

Just convert it into Python code and you're set! The reason this is is because you're not telling saying to first raise 4 to the 2nd power, and raise the result to the third power, but you'r actually saying raise 4 to the power of 2 raised to the power of 3.

Hope that helps!